# Mongoose - access populate field from within schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a schema which references another model. Something like

```
var bookSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    series: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Series' }
});
```

Now I have a function in the book schema which needs access to that `series`. I want to do something like

```
bookSchema.methods.fullTitle = function() {
    return [this.series.title, this.title].join(" - ");
}
```

but obviously that doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate the referenced model prior to being able to access its properties. Using your existing setup, you could do something similar to the following:

```
bookSchema.methods.fullTitle = function() {
  this.populate('series', function(err, result) {
    return [result.series.title, result.title].join(" - ");
  });
}
```

See Mongoose Population for more details on this.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Oh wow, didn't realize you could call `populate` on `this`. Thanks!